# Short question about $|\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx|=\int_{a}^{b}|f(x)|dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I have 2 very similar questions and short questions here:

1. If $|\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx|=\int_{a}^{b}|f(x)|dx$, must $f(x) \geq 0$ for $x \in (a,b)$? I have an intuition that this is false, but can not prove it. Maybe the use of a counterexample like $cos(x)$ would work?
2. Similarly, if $\int_{a}^{c_2}f(x)dx+\int_{c_1}^{b}f(x)dx=\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$ for $c_1, c_2 \in (a, b)$ with $c_1< c_2$, then must $f(x)=0$ for $x \in (a,b)$? On the surface, this looks alot like one of the inherent properties of integrals, where to get the integral from $[a,b]$ you can choose a midpoint $c$ between a and b and break it into 2 parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No, let $f(x) = -1,$ then $$\left| \int_a^b -1dx\right|= \left| -\int_a^b 1dx\right|=\int_a^b|-1|dx$$
2. No, let $f(x)\mid_{[c_1,c_2]}=0$, and let $f(x)$ be your favorite, non-zero integrable function on the rest of $(a,b).$

Answer (score 3):

1. $f$ can also be always negative. However, these are the only possibilities. Indeed, put $f_+=\max(f,0)$ and $f_-=\max(-f,0)$. Then $f=f_+-f_-$ and $\lvert f\rvert=f_++f_-$, so $\int f=\int f_+-\int f_-$ whereas $\int\lvert f\rvert=\int f_++\int f_-$ (all integrals on the interval $[a,b]$) and noting that these are sums/differences of nonnegative numbers, the claim follows that either $\int f_+=0$ or $\int f_-=0$.
2. Not necessarily, this is just saying that $\int_{c_1}^{c_2}f=0$, for instance $f=\cos$, $c_1=0$, and $c_2=2\pi$.